# Conditional mutual information $I(X;Y|Z)$

Tags: information-theory, mutual-information

If there is a function $Y=f(Z)$, is the following mutual information equal to zero?
\begin{align}
I(X;Y|Z)=0
\end{align}
Intuitively, it is correct. But how can we prove this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The mutual information is given by:

$$ I(X; Y \mid Z) = 0 $$

This measures the amount of information that $X$ and $Y$ share, given the knowledge of $Z$. If $Y$ is a function of $Z$ (i.e., $Y = f(Z)$), then once $Z$ is known, $Y$ is completely determined by $Z$ and does not depend on $X$. This means that knowing $X$ does not provide any additional information about $Y$ once $Z$ is known.

To formalize this, we use the definition of conditional mutual information:

$$ I(X; Y \mid Z) = H(Y \mid Z) - H(Y \mid X, Z) $$

where $H(Y \mid Z)$ is the conditional entropy of $Y$ given $Z$, and $H(Y \mid X, Z)$ is the conditional entropy of $Y$ given both $X$ and $Z$.

Since $Y$ is a function of $Z$, once $Z$ is known, $Y$ is completely determined. Therefore, $H(Y \mid Z) = 0$ because there is no uncertainty in $Y$ once $Z$ is known.

Similarly, $H(Y \mid X, Z) = 0$ because, again, once $Z$ is known, $Y$ is completely determined regardless of $X$.

So, we have:

$$ I(X; Y \mid Z) = 0 - 0 = 0 $$

This shows that the conditional mutual information between $X$ and $Y$, given $Z$, is zero when $Y$ is a function of $Z$. The presence of $Z$ removes any uncertainty about $Y$, making the additional knowledge of $X$ irrelevant for predicting $Y$.